# How to access web page from c #, but using open session in mozilla

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to access a web page, for example, to facebook, but using the session I already have open in mozilla firefoz. i mean, I want  to access to facebook (for example), but already being logged from the browser, and so not have to log in from the app. Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to access another program's memory space? Or just bring the browser up front?

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can create your own web view application, but if you want to use from the resources from the other apps, you have to use the cookie that sets on the browser's storage.

Please explain to me what do you want to do exactly, may I could help you!

Comment: Hi,thanks for answering.I want to log in to this website from my c# app(http://ewomoney.site/),so as you can see,this webpage has a login,so,i have logged in to this website from my explorer,mozilla.What i want to do,is that when i enter to this site from c#,it does not ask for my login,i mean,it uses the session that i have on my explorer.Btw,can you write me to cristiansori2@gmail.com?I need help with another question.Thanks